# Redirect traffic to particular instance from load balancer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am using the [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) elastic load balancer for my application. For testing purposes, I need to hit a particular application instance. Is there a way to hit the specified instance from the EC2 load balancer?

For example, for my load balancer http://myloadbalancer.com I have two instances attached, ec21 and ec22. If I need to hit ec22, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the management console, under particular Load Balancer and Instances section just delete ec22 from the list.

Once you completed all tests - add this instance back behind your LB.

Is it what you meant?

Comment: No, I have an end point to read the log of particular instance, this is for non-admins, so incase if anyone want to see the log file of a particular server, I am checking whether they can go to that instance. I can always do it physically login into the server. I am checking whether this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Access your instance with direct internal hostname via VPN or from another instance with elastic IP configured.
For example: ip-172-31-7-112.ec2.internal